# How to define default language behind selected one for backend

Tags: magento-2.1, backend, localisation, language

I've selected Spanish language for the back end and the translation is not completed. I understand that, but there is a problem: if translation is not available, the text is shown in German.

I can't find anywhere why this is happening.

How can I define English as default (or "in case of not finding") language?

How can I remove German as module (`magento/language-ge_ge`).

I've tried but it says that has dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can check what the default store view language. I think it is because that can be German. 
You can try running this command:-

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR
```

Comment: I've executed this command a hundred times, only en_GB and en_US appears. Any other idea?

Comment: Is your locale for users store based or website based? I mean what if You set the default store to English.

Comment: I've switched backend to english in System->permision->All users admin. And no trace of german. But not all the admins are good english readers.